# Can certificate store be placed in application.ini instead of php.ini

Tags: php, apache, curl, zend-framework, php-openssl

I am working on `Zend-Framework 1.12` and had to make an `https` request from the application. I did it by the following way:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$client->setAdapter($adaptor);
$client->setConfig(array('keepalive' => true));
$reCaptchaData = json_encode(array());
$client->setRawData($reCaptchaData, 'application/json');
$response = $client->request('POST');
```

I was getting errors like:

```
Error in cURL request: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Found that I had to add the CA certificates, I downloaded [one](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and added its path to my `php.ini`.

```
curl.cainfo="path"
openssl.cafile="path"
```

It works fine.

1. But can't I add this to my `application.ini`? When I try it there it doesn't work.
2. Does `application.ini` work as an extension of `php.ini`?
   But can't load modules or certificates, because that this done by Apache on a restart? Apache reads the `php.ini` on a restart and loads everything (I have the path for my `php.ini` in `httpd.conf`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to PHP's manual (http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php), `openssl.cafile` is `PHP_INI_PERDIR` changeable.

That means, if you read http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php, that you cannot change it at a script level:

> PHP_INI_PERDIR    Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

So, no, you won't be able to set those 2 settings in Zend's `application.ini`, but you could do it in a `.htaccess` file via:

```
php_value curl.cainfo "path"
php_value openssl.cafile "path"
```

Keep in mind this will only work if PHP is loaded as an Apache module.

If you use PHP-FPM, you'll need to create a specific pool and alter the values there. It's a bit more complicated in this case, and only doable if you have access to the server's config.

`application.ini` is not an extension of `php.ini` as it's got its own syntax, like the `phpSettings.` prefix.

What you could also look for is `.user.ini` as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

In order for this to work, you'll need to set a value for `user_ini.filename` in `php.ini`, and of course an additional user ini file (you can't use `application.ini` as a `.user.ini` file).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the provided links.